# Multiple partitions on one disk in esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi

I know it is not recommended to have multiple partitions on a single drive. But I want to have two drives handling the VMs in a mirror with separate partitions. But I cant create more datastores on a drive. I think i can be done since I have been able to do it on other esxi systems before. The "New datastore" in the corner of the page where my disks shows up is grey. I have tried using the partedUtil tool but I cannot seem to get it.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two disks to mirror, wouldn't you want to put them together in a RAID1? If you want to create a second datastore on the same disk, you will have to use partedUtil or fdisk. Afterwards, you'll have to create the filesystem inside the partition with vmkfstools for it to show up in vSphere.

This guide will show you how to do that:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009829

Comment: Two partitions on a single disk is not a "mirror." You are thinking of RAID 1, which is two physical disks mirrored to each other.

Comment: I realize that, but I figured I answer the question as it was asked. If he RAID1's the disks he can set up two partitions on the virtual disk. Not sure why someone would do that unless they are experimenting with storage.

Comment: I meant to direct that to the OP.